# Wait until elasticsearch index is filled

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to write an integration test for the communication with elasticsearch. My idea is to push some records in the setUp method and then let the test make some requests. My initialization using Elastica framework looks like this:

```
protected function setUp() {
  parent::setUp();

  $this->setApplicationConfig([
    'modules' => [
    ],
    'module_listener_options' => [
      'config_static_paths' => [
        'module/MyModule/tests/resources/config/elasticsearch.yaml',
      ],
      'check_dependencies' => true,
    ]
  ]);
  $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()
    ->setFactory('MyNamespace\ElasticSearchClient', 'MyNamespace\ElasticSearch\ClientFactory');

  self::$indexName = strtolower(uniqid('PHPUnit_'));
  self::$searchClient = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->get('\MyNamespace\ElasticSearchClient');
  $this->articleIdList = [
    'even' => [],
    'odd' => [],
  ];

  $searchIndex = new Index(self::$searchClient->getClient(), self::$indexName);
  $searchIndex->create();

  $documentCount = 1000;
  $searchDocumentBulk = new Bulk(self::$searchClient->getClient());
  $searchDocumentBulk->setIndex($searchIndex);
  for ($id = 1; $id <= $documentCount; $id++) {
    $article = [
      'client' => 'test',
      'content' => 'PHPUnit Test Text ' . ($id % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd') . ' ' . $id,
    ];
    $searchDocumentBulk->addDocument(new ElasticaDocument($id, $article, 'PHPUnit_Article'));
    $this->articleIdList[($id % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd')][] = $id;
  }
  $response = $searchDocumentBulk->send();
  $this->assertEquals($documentCount, $response->count());
}
```

All my tests fail because of different result count. I think the reason for this is that the records are pushed asynchronizely to the server and my tests begin to fast so not all documents are indexed at this moment.
But I found no possibility to wait until the index is created and all documents are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run something like `sleep(5000)` just after your setup and before your actual tests? Elasticsearch probably need some time to index documents.

Comment: Yes that's possible. The problem is to find out the correct sleep time. Because the test suite could run on different servers with different performances, the time could be perfect on the first system but too short on the second one. And too many seconds are also problematic because the test suite contains many tests and that's why I want to keep the runtime only as long as necessary.